# Query condition where 2 data will be joined in 1 array if they have the same level

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a function where 2 data will be joined in 1 row after generation when the button is clicked. But the thing is there's no condition or whatsoever. My target is to have a condition where players with the same level will be joined in 1 row. If the players doesn't have the same level, hence it should be alone in the row with a label "no match found"

> Lamok 1 = 1980 LEVEL vs LAMOK 5 1980 LEVEL // This is my target if they have the same level

> Lamok 1 = 1980 LEVEL NO MATCH FOUND // This is my target if they don't have the same level.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn bg-gradient-info btn-xs" id="matchingbutton">match players</button>  
           

          
           <table  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped is-narrow is-hoverable">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
               
                       <th class="bg-danger text-center">red</th>
                       <th class="bg-danger text-center">level</th>
                       <th class="bg-primary text-center">blue</th>
                       <th class="bg-primary text-center">level</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody id="playerdisplay">
               </tbody>
               
           </table>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).on('click','#matchingbutton',function(){


$.ajax({
      url:"<?=site_url('controller/players')?>",
       method:"POST",
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(data){
           $('#playerdisplay').html(data);
            
        
       }
       })
})
```

**Controller:**

```
function players(){
        
        $query=$this->model->playerss();
      
      $a=0;
  
        $row = '<tr>';
        foreach($query as $rows){
            
            
            
            $row .= '><td>'.$rows->player.'</td><td>'.$rows->level.'</td>';
            
            $a++;
          
            if($a%2==0)
            {
                $row.= '</tr>';
               
            }

  
        }

    
       
        $row.= '</tr>';
        echo json_encode($row);
       
    }
```

**Model:**

```
 function playerss(){

// I need some condition here if player and another player has the same LEVEL, match them/ join them in 1 row. If they don't have the same level, label it as a "no match found"
        $this->db->order_by('rand()');
        $query = $this->db->get('entry');
        return $query->result();
        
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not complete. *players with the same level will be joined in 1 row* - (1) in your screenshot some player pairs in the same row have different level value (2) you have not provided **strong criteria** for to select a pair when more than one row to be paired exists.

Comment: The reason why they're matched even tho they don't have the same level because my current function doesn't have any condition YET. That's why i need a suggestion or any help on how i can make a condition where players with same level should be in the same row. I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: Divide to groups and enumerate (starting from zero!) in groups while ordering by the level. If the difference between current and previous row is above the accuracy then increase group number and restart enumeration. Then group by the group number and number in a group DIV 2. On MySQL 8+ use window functions in CTE, on MySQL 5+ use user-defined variables.